# What degree do you need to present a poster in a conference?

Tags: conference, presentation, poster, masters-post-phd

Hi there I just finished my Master’s degree and in a couple of months there is a conference about my thesis topic that I would like to have a PhD about. My question is can I present a poster or should I own a PhD already? I read that you can present a poster even with a Master’s degree but my professor told me that’s not true. Should I ask another professor if he is interesting in collaborating with me for a poster or is it dumb? I was thinking on working with the professor I wanted to do my PhD thesis with and maybe work on something small is it possible in only two months? I don’t know how much time you need to prepare a poster.
Thank you.

Comment: Can you describe the conference? Is this the kind of conference which is selective about abstracts and acts something like a peer-reviewed journal? Is the conference aimed at younger researchers (PhD students/postdocs)? Did the conference say anything about poster submissions that give the impression that they are not open to anyone?

Comment: Why not just ask the conference organisers? There’s no hard and fast rule as far as I know

Comment: @user438383 I thought it may be a dumb question and I didn’t wanna seem like I am overrate myself but yes you are right

Comment: @TrevorGunn the conference is open even for post graduate students, the only description was that there would be a 30 mins poster session nothing about who can present. I don’t know how these conferences are called I think it’s just an academic conference where Postdoc, PhD students and professors present their study results. I think that it is aimed in students in general from post grads to post docs.

Comment: @Mathematician don’t worry about that, nobody will think you are dumb for asking an honest question like that.

Comment: You sound a bit like you want to prepare a new result just for a poster session. It may vary between fields, but at least in my area of math, posters are more used to advertise existing or upcoming results. That being said, I have seen people present the results from their master-thesis, so that might be a simple solution.

Comment: @mlk Thank you so much for your answer at first. I don’t want to prepare something just to be at a poster session I just want to start working on new things at mathematics but I don’t have someone to guide me. I just thought that it would be a great opportunity to present something in front of professors with similar scientific interests and it may help me on my future studies. My first idea was doing a bit more work on my master thesis but my professor told me that’s not possible, and I’m a bit confused.

Answer (score 5):

You do not need any specific degree to make and present a poster.

Nobody will check degrees at any point, the only important thing is to produce good work, get it accepted at a conference, and follow conference instructions to build a proper poster, and present it.

In conferences I have seen undergraduate students presenting posters, and even by researchers without degrees (for example, Chris Olah, in Machine Learning).